# how to get checked radio button with jQuery after changing the default checked="checked"

Tags: jquery, radio-button, checked

I have a group of radio buttons with one of them checked by default:

```
<input type='radio' name='myradios' value='flat'>
<input type='radio' name='myradios' value='ball' checked='checked'>
<input type='radio' name='myradios' value='list'>
```

How can I get the checked value after they have been changed (another one was clicked)

I tried `jQuery("input[name=myradios]:checked").val()`, but unfortunately
`jQuery("input[name=myradios]:checked")` gives a list that ALWAYS includes the one that originally had the checked="checked" property, so depending on "luck" (order of the buttons, whether the one I clicked is before or after the one that was the default) I do get good or wrong value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('input[name="myradios"]').change(function() {
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(':radio[name=myradios]:checked').val()` should work fine. [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HEAR5/).

Answer (score -1):

The `.val` method will give you the checked value.

```
$('input[name="myradios"]').change(function() {
   console.log($(this).val());
});
```

The [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HEAR5/1/).